# Conditional find and replace pargraph mark in Word document

Tags: vba, ms-word

I want to replace pargraph marks in word according to the style of previous and next words. I tried the following macro but did not work. Do you have any idea on how to fix this ?

```
  Sub RemoveParagraph() 


  With Selection
  Set rng = .Range
  With .Find        
    .Text = "^p"        
    .Execute
  End With

  Do While .Find.Found
    If (Selection.Previous(Unit:=wdWord, Count:=1).Style = "Style1") And (Selection.Next(Unit:=wdWord, Count:=1).Style = "Style2") Then
    .Find.Replacement.Text = " "
    End If
    .Find.Execute
  Loop

End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Please describe HOW the code "did not work".

Comment: @CindyMeister the code was executing but did not replace the characters.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple flaws in your code. For example:

• Unless you clear any prior & find/replace expressions & configuration, they may impact your code.

• Unless you set text wrapping to 'stop', you're liable to end up with an endless loop.

• The Find will continue beyond your selection. So, unless you test whether each match is in your selected range, it will continue processing beyond that.

• Using '.Find.Replacement.Text = " "' within the loop won't work.

• Testing multiple conditions via And is less efficient than testing them individually.

• Turning off screen updating improves efficiency and reduces screen flicker.

Try:

```
Sub RemoveParagraph()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim Rng As Range
With Selection
  Set Rng = Selection.Range
  With .Find
    .ClearFormatting
    .Replacement.ClearFormatting
    .Text = "^p"
    .Replacement.Text = ""
    .Forward = True
    .MatchWildcards = False
    .Wrap = wdFindStop
    .Execute
  End With
  Do While .Find.Found
    If .InRange(Rng) = False Then Exit Do
    If .Characters.First.Previous.Style = "Style1" Then
      If .Characters.Last.Next.Style = "Style2" Then .Text = " "
    End If
    .Collapse wdCollapseEnd
    .Find.Execute
  Loop
End With
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for the tips @macropod, but the code did not work. When I execute it it goes through paragraph marks one by one, so I need to execute it several times, and it did not replace any of the paragraph marks matching the condition.

Comment: It works for me. Did you actually select the range to be processed and specify the correct Styles?

Comment: Thank you very much! I run it again and it worked this time !